# Apart from Momotaro's Sea Eagles, did any other animated propaganda survive WWII?

Tags: anime-history, momotaro

The question is mostly in the title; When discussing propaganda through anime, most articles refer to Momotaro's Divine Sea Eagles.

[image: momotaro screenshot]

There was definitely other anime which were produced during wartime to promote the army's cause - but a lot of it was destroyed by the Americans after Japan's defeat.

Is there any other surviving animated Japanese propaganda from WWII?

Comment: [1934 Japanese cartoon with evil Mickey Mouse](http://boingboing.net/2008/03/17/1936-japanese-cartoo.html)

Comment: @user1306322 I've turned the comment into an answer, with a working YouTube link. Unfortunately, I don't know enough to provide any commentary or analysis about the anime films.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Toy Box Series Episode 3: Picture Book 1936" (オモチャ箱シリーズ第3話 絵本一九三六年) could count, depending on when you regard WWII and the second Sino-Japanese war as starting. ([1934 in Anime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1934_in_anime) English Wikipedia page listing it)

Here's a [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icVu-acHlpU). Warning: some of the comments in the comment section are racist.

From Boing Boing: [<s>1936</s> 1934 Japanese cartoon with evil Mickey Mouse](http://boingboing.net/2008/03/17/1936-japanese-cartoo.html)

> Mickey Mouse flies in with a squadron of mouse-headed pterodactyls to
>   attack an island populated with cute Japanese animals, including a
>   surreal Felix the Cat with sausage-link arms. Link (Via Pink Tentacle)
>
> > [I]n the aftermath of the Mukden (Manchurian) Incident and Japan’s
> >     announced withdrawal from the League of Nations after the League
> >     concluded they were the aggressor, right wing elements in the country
> >     started an opinion campaign that once the Five Power naval limitation
> >     treaty ran out in 1936, America was planning to attack Japanese
> >     possessions, so Japan needed to expand its military… just in case..
> >     Apparently, this cartoon was an attempt to stir the pot."'

Browsing Wikipedia's XXXX in anime list, I came across [Sankichi the Monkey: The Air Combat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1942_in_anime) in the 1942 year. Here's a [YouTube link featuring English subtitles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTKCfyBKvhw).